# How to retrieve particular word using awk command

Tags: linux, networking, awk, sed, router

if i run the command in cisco ios device " show run | i location " , i may get the output as "snmp-server location Nova South, United Kingdom (GHDY2892)"

I want to fetch all the words after 'location' in that output. Location may differ accordingly.

Can we use awk command to get it.

```
 echo {{ output.stdout[0] }} |   awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="location")print $(i+1)}'
```

This command will only print first word after location but i want to get all the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel iteration is a bit heavy weight for the problem. What do you think about this one:
`echo "snmp-server location Nova South, United Kingdom (GHDY2892)" | awk '{sub(".*location ", "", $0); print $0}'`